# Partial Derivatives and Linear Map

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Proposition:

Suppose that $T : R^n \to R^m$
is the linear transformation defined by

$T(x) = Mx$

for some m × n matrix $M$. Then

$DT(x) = M$

for all points $x \in R^n$

where $D$ is the partial derivative matrix. (Jacobian?)

---

Question:

I don't understand what is being said. $T(x)$ is a linear transformation on $x$. How does the partial derivative of $T(x)$ lead to the transformation matrix. Neither do I have an algebraic intuition nor a geometric one.

---

Further,
How is the total derivative of $g(x,y,z)$ equal to $ Dg(x,y,z) \begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y\\
z \end{pmatrix}$?

This is stated without proof. There is a chance, I made a wrong interpretation so I am pasting the portion of the text where it appears.

[image: Total Derivative]

Is it that the change in $x$ in all dimensions of the output of $g(x,y,z)$ multiplied by $x$ and similar for y and z gives a total derivative. I don't seem to understand.I know the total derivative is a derivative taking into account that other variables are not constant during differentiation by one variable.

Comment: Regarding the second part: Confusingly, there are [many things](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) which are given the name "total derivative". But this doesn't appear to match up with any of them. Are you sure of the transcription? It could be that $x, y, z$ are functions of a single variable $t$, and the matrix on the right could be $\begin{pmatrix}x'(t) \\ y'(t) \\ z'(t)\end{pmatrix}$. Then this would just be the chain rule.

Comment: @DylanMoreland, I have added a picture of the part where it appears.

Comment: Thanks for scanning; that really helps us. [It would be good to say what $g$ and $f$ are, too.] I would not use the same letters for $(1, 0)$ (the point at which you're finding the total derivative; maybe write a general point as $(a, b)$) and the vector $(x, y)$ on which you are evaluating the derivative.

Comment: @DylanMoreland, I added the whole problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For algebraic intuition:  The derivative of a function is the best linear approximation to it.  In the case when the function is linear already, it's its own best linear approximation, hence it's its own derivative.

As a reminder, for multivariate $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, the derivative $Df(x)$ at the point $x\in \mathbb{R}^m$ is defined to be a linear map $A:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x) - Ah}{\|h\|}=0$$

It's not too hard to show that if $A$ exists, it's unique.

Now, we simply check that for $T(x) = Mx$, everything works.

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \dfrac{T(x+h)-T(x) - Mh}{\|h\|} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \dfrac{M(x+h)-Mx-Mh}{\|h\|} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{Mx+Mh-Mx-Mh}{\|h\|}=0$$ since the numerator is $0$.

**Edit to address the comment**

In answer to the comment, the derivative *at a point* is the best linear approximation at that point (though we think of the point as being shifted to the origin).  Thus, in your example of $f(x) = x^3$, the derivative, $3x^2$, at a point (say $x=2$) gives a slope of $12$.  The linear approximation this corresponds to is $12x$.

In fact, this issue is one it took me a long time to come to terms with.  For functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, we think of the derivative of the whole function as a new function $f'(x)$.  With more variables, we change view point:  The derivative of a function *at a point* is itself a function (linear transformation).  The relationship between the 2 is that a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ can be identified with a single real number $\mathbb{R}$ via a pretty canonical choice of basis.  The derivative of a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ *at a point* $p$ is the linear map "multiply by $f'(p)$".

Comment: I wrote "the derivative... is defined to be..." but perhaps what I should have said is "one definition of the derivative is..."

Comment: 1. In the definition of the derivative, should it be $f(x+h) - f(x)$ instead of $f(x+h) - f(h)$ or am I missing something. 2. I understood the interpretation but I can't seem to completely appreciate the fact that a derivative is a linear approximation. How is $3x^2$ a linear approximation to $x^3$?

Comment: You're right about 1, I'll fix it.  I'll also add a bit to address 2.